# Apache crashes with Parent: child process exited with status 3221226356

Tags: apache, proxy, mod-ssl

Apache crashes and I get the following error in the apache log:

AH00428: Parent: child process exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting.

Backtrace:

```
Count:    2
Exception #:  0XC0000008
Stack:        
    ntdll!KiRaiseUserExceptionDispatcher+0x3a
    KERNELBASE!CloseHandle+0x1b
    libapr_1!apr_shm_size_get+0x27d
    libapr_1!apr_shm_destroy+0x12
    mod_socache_shmcb+0x161c
    mod_ssl!ssl_run_proxy_post_handshake+0x8d12
    mod_ssl!ssl_run_pre_handshake+0x3d97
    libapr_1!apr_pool_clear+0x6e
    httpd!OPENSSL_Applink+0xcef
    httpd!OPENSSL_Applink+0x1f98
    KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
    ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34
```

Seems to have to do with mod_ssl. I do have a http proxy set up in a https virtual host. However, the same error appears in the Apache log even if I comment out the proxy portion of the config file. This error also tends to be followed by a couple of MySQL errors in the Windows application log complaining about a lost connection. I think that might just be because Apache crashed while the connections were open. I am using the latest versions of Apache 2.4.20, PHP 7.0.8, and MySQL 5.7. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Continued to get the error when hitting https. Used abs.exe to test it and almost always get the error within 3 tests of 1000 requests. Usually get it in the first few hundred when hitting a wordpress site over SSL. Get it when all plugins are disabled. Get it hitting a website not using wordpress at all. Tried it with all extensions disabled except mysqli (needed to load the website). In other words, I can't seem to use Apache 2.4 with SSL and PHP 7. Tried basically totally simplifying the config files. Tried totally replacing the installs. The only thing that solves the error is using PHP 5.

Comment: Also get this error from abs.exe: SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
apr_pollset_add(): Not enough space (12)